# Mention.js doesn't stop suggesting users

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, sqlite

I wanted to test out something before I add it to my project: a Twitter-like mention user function from GitHub: https://github.com/jakiestfu/Mention.js.

The problem is, the way his demo works is, is that he created some data manually and retrieves that data. I had to modify it a AJAX (which I'm not very good at to use my database).

The issue is, whenever I write `@`, the script brings up users perfectly, but after choosing one from the list, the list won't go away and keeps suggesting users. On top of that, after choosing a user whatever I type after the user name, then hit the return key, all the text I typed after the username will disappear completely.

Dependencies:

1. bootstrap type head
2. jquery
3. mention.js

My Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('fetch.php', function(data) {
         $("#textarea").mention({
           users: data
            });
        });
            
    });
```

fetch.php (it is very basic, it is for testing only):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$con =new PDO("sqlite:database.db");
$user_data = array();

$users = $con->query("select * from users");

foreach($users as $key => $val)
{
$user_data[$key]['name'] = $val['f_name'];
$user_data[$key]['username'] = $val['name'];
$user_data[$key]['image'] = " ";

}

echo json_encode($user_data);
```

This is the code, the HTML is only one text area with the id=textarea.

The original script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            
            $("#full").mention({
                users: [{
                    name: 'Lindsay Made',
                    username: 'LindsayM',
                    image: 'http://placekitten.com/25/25'
                }, {
                    name: 'Rob Dyrdek',
                    username: 'robdyrdek',
                    image: 'http://placekitten.com/25/24'
                }, {
                    name: 'Rick Bahner',
                    username: 'RickyBahner',
                    image: 'http://placekitten.com/25/23'
                }, 
            });
        });
```

If I use the original script, it works perfectly with no issues whatsoever, but the moment I change it to my script the writing issues start to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly fetch the data by alias. Better then foreach loop in this case.

```
$users = $con->query("select f_name as name, name as username from users");
```

Then print the data to the console, in your javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('fetch.php', function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         $("#textarea").mention({
           users: data
            });
        });
            
    });
```

Comment: this is currently in a testing environment that is why the code is messy . i did change it however but still didn't fix my issue